# Logic for Number Of Pages for overlapping distance

Tags: c#, overlap

I need to find number of sub pages of screenshots.,
Given :,
1) total height of page,
2) height of 1 sub-page,
3) Every consecutive screenshot height overlaps the above screen by "5" pixels

```
Ex : Page height = 100 px
     1 Screen height (subpage) = 20px
     Then,
     1st screenshot : 0px to 20 px
     2nd screenshot : 15px to 35px.. and so on
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private int GetSubPageCount(int heightOfPage)
{
    int heightOfSubPage = 20;
    int overlap = 5;
    // that gives you count of completely filled sub pages
    int subPageCount = (heightOfPage - overlap) / (heightOfSubPage - overlap);

    // if last sub page is not completely filled, than add one page
    if ((heightOfPage - overlap) % (heightOfSubPage - overlap) > 0)
        subPageCount++;

    return subPageCount;
}
```

Or you can use floating-point numbers with rounding to smallest integer value that is greater or equal than completely filled sub-pages count:

```
private int GetSubPageCount(int heightOfPage)
{
    int heightOfSubPage = 20;
    int overlap = 5;
    return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(heightOfPage - overlap) / (heightOfSubPage - overlap));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was also able to solve the same using arithmetic progression :
AddedLag = (pageHeight/subpageHeight)*overlap
Thus, extra pages := Math.ceiling(AddedLag/subpageHeight)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an easy formula:

```
  number = (page_height - overlap) / (subpage_height - overlap)
```

If number is *fractional* one (e.g. 5.123) you should *round it up* (5.123 to 6).

For instance, if page_height = 100, subpage_height = 20 and overlap = 5 we can derive that

```
number = (100 - 5) / (20 - 5) = 6.333333 
number = 7 (rounded up)
```

Sample code:

```
public static int SubPageCount(int pageHeight, int height, int overlap) {
  int result = (pageHeight - overlap) / (height - overlap);

  // If there's a fractional part - i.e. remainder in not 0
  // one should round the result up: add 1 
  if (((pageHeight - overlap) % (height - overlap)) != 0)
    result += 1;

  return result;
}
```